# If many apples are bad. Then which of the below sentences correctly describes that many apples are bad

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

If many apples are bad. Then which the below sentences correctly describes that many apples are bad.

1. An apple are bad. Such apples are many in number.
2. An apple are bad. Such an apple is many in number.

I tried to find "such" meaning it refers to "type". I am not too sure.

I really need to know which one is correct because I need to build upon these sentences. I need to make sentences in that format.

Pls help.

Tks in advance
Joe

Comment: Neither option is correct because of the first sentence "An apple are bad." *An apple* is singular and must use the singular form of the verb **to be**.

Comment: I hate to be a meanie but really, if you don't know the difference between a singular subject that takes a singular verb and a plural subject that takes a plural verb, you will need to start at zero.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem.  The example with apples is completely wrong. I think you might have a different problem that you are trying to solve with "such". But you haven't told us what the real problem is, only what your solution to the problem is.  This makes it hard to write a useful answer.

Comment: Son, you need to learn the difference between one (singular) and many (plural). Don't try to write sentences until you get the basics down first. Please. You'll only confuse yourself.

Comment: 'Many [of the] apples are bad' or 'There are m any bad apples' is the only way to say it. It makes no sense to try to express it in two sentences.

Comment: It's hard to believe that anyone would post such a question, even a beginner, as in most languages there is a difference between singular and plural. I just wonder in what universe the OP thinks this is English. By the way, it almost sounds like Belters' English in the sci fi series: The Expanse. A real treat if  you're into that.

Comment: @Lambie It's unnecessary to take a shot at a new contributor, especially one so obviously new to English. Further, there are language families (Koreanic, Japonic, ...) where there is no agreement with number, and plural forms of nouns are optional.

Answer (score 3):

Neither sentence is idiomatic or natural English.

They are also not grammatical English, but that is a minor flaw that could be fixed.  But even if the grammar errors were fixed, the sentences would be utterly odd and not idiomatic.

Do not try to "build upon" such sentences. They are not a good foundation for constructing clear sentences in English.